# Allow Access to a Website only for specific IPs

Tags: asp.net

I have a website  running in IIS 6.0, the website is an asp.net with framework 4.0
We have an application that is not hosted on the client, is hosted in our side. The client ask to allow access only for specific IPs.

So I added the list of IPs in the web.config, like this:

```
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">    
    <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
    <add ipAddress="XXX.XXX.XXX.114" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>
<add ipAddress="XXX.XXX.XXX.85" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>
   </ipSecurity>
 </security>
```

In this example only two IPs have access to the side.
Should I need to do an extra step? because is not working. Is it the best way to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer is in this link [IP Security](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity)

```
    Compatibility

    Version   Notes

IIS 7.5     The <ipSecurity> element was not modified in IIS 7.5.

IIS 7.0     The <ipSecurity> element was introduced in IIS 7.0.

IIS 6.0     The <ipSecurity> element replaces the IIS 6.0 IPSecurity metabase property.
```